# Certificate signed by unknown authority Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode, ibm-blockchain

I'm trying to create a channel for my hyperledger fabric network but I've been stuck for over two weeks with this error :

> [policies] SignatureSetToValidIdentities -> WARN 00d invalid identity: certificate subject=CN=Admin@productionlaborg.supplychain.com,OU=admin,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US serialnumber=332150209750411695579251324251304242011 error="the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification failure" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "ca.productionlaborg.supplychain.com")"

know that I export the correct path of the "MSP folder" of the admin "Admin@productionlaborg" how created the channel.

**Please I need Help**

Comment: Have a look at the shell script called createChannel.sh which is in the scripts folder under test-network, which is part of the fabric-samples provided by Hyperledger. The script tells you all you need to know. You could follow each step and try to do it manually, or else modify the script to suit your own naming conventions.